# Porque isso não funciona no meu controle de usuário?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um código que gostaria de coloca-lo no controle de usuário do meu windows forms, mas ele não faz alterações no Form1, qual o motivo?

Código:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    var tab = new TabPage();
    var aba = new Abas();
    tab.Text = "Guia " + ((int)f1.tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    f1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
    tab.Controls.Add(aba);
    f1.tabControl1.SelectTab(tab);
    aba.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

Caso eu coloque este código em um botão do próprio Form1, ele funciona normalmente.

Comment: resolveu seu problema ? coloca mais informações para tentarmos ajudar

Comment: Ainda não, dei uma modificada no post.

Comment: você está com os dois forms abertos ao mesmo tempo ?

Comment: e ao clicar nesse botão, ele deve adicionar essa tab ?

Comment: Sim, na verdade o controle de usuário fica dentro do form1.

Comment: então, você ao que me parece está instanciando novamente o Form1, sendo que este já foi instanciado e está aberto na tela, poste o código de quando você manda abrir o Form1, ou o Form2 (não sei qual abre primeiro)

Comment: Não existe form2. O programa abre o form1 e o controle de usuário é instanciado dentro dele.

Comment: Pode postar esse controle?

Comment: Não tem muito o que mostrar, ele tem alguns butões e só, no caso, o button5 (do qual eu estou tendo problema) está no post.

Comment: é porque não faz muito sentido você criar um controle, mas a função dele é alterar o form1... então queria entender realmente o que você fez. mas de qualquer forma seu problema está sendo a instancia, no evento do button5, utilize a propriedade Parent como mostrei no exemplo que deve funcionar

Comment: Deu erro: `System.ArgumentException: 'Não é possível adicionar o controle de nível superior a um controle.'`

Comment: esse controle que você fez, só serve para o Form1 ?

Comment: Sim. Ele é usado somente no Form1.

Comment: nesse caso, desaconselho criar um controle desse tipo, não será útil em nenhum outro local da aplicação, seria bem mais simples colocar os componentes na tela diretamente

Comment: Mas eu preciso que cada tabpage seja uma coisa diferente, mais ou menos como funciona as abas de um navegador.

Comment: Consegui colocando um botão no Form1 que sobreponha esse botão, de qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que, você abre o `Form1`, dentro dele você tenha um comando que abra o `Form2`, e no `Form2`, um botão para adicionar a `tabPage` no `Form1`, o código deveria ficar assim:

**Form1.cs:**

```
 //Evento que abre o Form2
 private void buttonAbrirForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form2 form = new Form2();
     form.Parent = this;
     form.Show();
 }
```

**Form2.cs:**

```
 //Evento que adiciona a tab no Form1
 private void buttonAddTabForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Form1 f1 = ((Form1)this.Parent);
    var tab = new TabPage();
    var aba = new Abas();
    tab.Text = "Guia " + ((int)f1.tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    f1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
    tab.Controls.Add(aba);
    f1.tabControl1.SelectTab(tab);
    aba.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

 }
```

*Há ainda como não passar o `Form1` como `Parent` do `Form2`, e de qualquer lugar da aplicação você acessar o `Form1`:*

```
    private void buttonAddTabForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f is Form1)
            {
                 Form1 f1 = ((Form1)f);
                 var tab = new TabPage();
                 var aba = new Abas();
                 tab.Text = "Guia " + ((int)f1.tabControl1.TabCount +1).ToString();
                 f1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
                 tab.Controls.Add(aba);
                 f1.tabControl1.SelectTab(tab);
                 aba.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Como falei nos comentários, acredito que não seja a situação para a criação de um userControl personalizado. Mas de qualquer forma eu fiz um que altera o Form1, e aqui funcionou perfeitamente:

Exemplo:

```
    //Evento do botão que está dentro do userControl1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent is Form1)
        {
            ((Form1)this.Parent).Text = "Texto foi alterado pelo controle";
        }
    }
```

No caso do seu Controle:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Parent is Form1)
    {
        Form1 f1 = ((Form1)this.Parent);
        var tab = new TabPage();
        var aba = new Abas();
        tab.Text = "Guia " + ((int)f1.tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        f1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
        tab.Controls.Add(aba);
        f1.tabControl1.SelectTab(tab);
        aba.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

Obs: Para que você acesse os controles de fora do form, a propriedade `modifiers` deve estar definida como `public`